# Multiple functions parameters generate from passed functions object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm creating a tool for auto-generate functions from passed functions.
How to make the typescript-typings don't mixins the parameters of the passed function

TypeScript Version: v3.6.3

```
type IActions<AS extends IDefinitions<AS>> = 
    Record<keyof AS, (...args: Parameters<AS[keyof AS]>) => any>;

export type IDefinitions<D> = Record<keyof D, (...args: any[]) => Generator>;

function creator <D extends IDefinitions<D>>(def: D): IActions<D> {
    return {} as any;
}


const u = creator({
    *getUser(name: string) {
        yield Promise.all([]);
    },
    *test(id: number, name: string) {
        yield Promise.race([]);
    },
})

// The function type is: getUser(...args: [string] | [number, string]): any
u.getUser()
```

Also can see the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Seems should return the right parameters, like so:

```
// getUser(name: string): any
u.actions.getUser('test');

// getUser(id: number, name: string): any
u.actions.test(123, 'test');
```